# Loop through a column to find first occurrence of special character for each location

Tags: python, regex, special-characters, data-manipulation, contains

There are two columns in the dataframe

```
location experience
a1       tech
a2       loyalty
a2       ‡€asd
a5       Ù…Ù
a5       completed
a6       
a7       --
a8       happy
a8       best
a9       for sure
a9       notgood
b1       amazing:
b1       /§!vision
b5       referral
```

1. how to loop through location and if special character is identified in the first row of experience, remove all locations. If the second row or other rows in Experience starts with special character, I dont have to remove it.

Example1:
b1       amazing:

b1       /§!vision

Here first row, experience value starts with letter, so I dont have to remove any rows with location value b1

Example2:
a5       Ù…Ù

a5       completed

Here first experience value starts with special character, so I have to remove all rows with location value a5

output as

```
location experience
a1       tech
a2       loyalty
a2       ‡€asd
a6 
a8       happy
a8       best
a9       for sure
a9       notgood
b1       amazing:
b1       /§!vision
b5       referral
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', engine='python')
df.fillna(value='', inplace=True)
df[df.experience.str.isalnum()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas `groupby` follow by [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html) to get the first row of `experience`. Then, use `str.match` to check if `experience` first row value starts with a letter.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
print(df)

location = df.groupby('location')

# get the first row of each group
loc_first = location.first()

# check if experience first row value starts with letter (or space?, 'a6' location)
exp_match = loc_first[~loc_first.experience.str.match(r'^[a-zA-Z\s]')]

# remove all rows with location
df = df[~df.location.isin(exp_match.index)]
print(df)
```

*df* output

```py
   location experience
0        a1       tech
1        a2    loyalty
2        a2      ‡€asd
5        a6
7        a8      happy
8        a8       best
9        a9   for sure
10       a9    notgood
11       b1   amazing:
12       b1  /§!vision
13       b5   referral
```